# Why gdm3 don't start on boot no more?

Tags: boot, gdm

Since i tried to change some driver and configuration for my GPU, gdm3 don't start on boot. Boot stop on the dell logo and i have to open a tty session and start gdm3 service manually.
Then everything is fine, there no problem, it's just a bit annoying.
I've been looking for a while but can't find a solution,...
Someone knows how to launch automatically gdm3 on boot ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be the roll-back the changes you made, if you must keep the current driver version, then probably researching the issue with the current version would be the best of course. From what I know, this is actually an issue where the boot process does not recognize the display manager to default to, and so it halts on the splash screen. This is either because the install is somehow either not correct anymore or the hook to which display manager it should launch is missing/broken.

proceed like this:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-$VERSION-generic linux-headers-$VERSION\*
sudo apt-get purge gdm3
sudo apt-get install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
reboot
```

Hope that works. And ofc replace the $VERSION for your current linux image version. `uname –r`